# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, import

So I am trying to import tensorflow on jupyter lab but this is the error that it show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzarS.png)
I've already installed tensorflow as shown in this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fanr1.png)

Can someone help me resolve this

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), paying close attention to the section where it says "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.". In your second screenshot, you are using `!pip install ....`. Replace that with the magic install command variation, `%pip install ...` and run that command again. When it completes restart the kernel and then run `import tensorflow as tf` again and see if it doesn't show module not found now. If this doesn't make sense, see ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands that are current best practice for use running inside modern Jupyter (even JupyterLite) to do installs from within the running kernel since the magic variations of the install commands insure that the installation occurs in the environment backing the running kernel.

Comment: <continued> [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues for certain users depending on how system is set up. That problem with use of the exclamation point inside Juptyer to do installs is what prompted the addition of the magic install commands in 2019. You should use the magic install commands for a better experience in Jupyter going forward, and use that as a gauge for determining updated sources of advice.

Comment: Instead of 3 lengthy comments, you could just write that in an answer. But interesting to know about the difference between `!` and `%`.